# Make twilio send an information to the app if twilio account status has changed

Tags: twilio

I need that the application could be aware if twilio account status has changed. There isn't any event that could do that. Is there any way to solve the problem so that the application could get the information about current status without any requests or handling errors?

Comment: Hello, what sort of account status are you talking about here? Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I mean "live", "suspended" etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is not, to my knowledge, a way to get a webhook regarding account status changes.

There are other warning systems though. All Twilio projects have a default email notification trigger that is hit when your balance reaches $5 so that you can go and top your account up and avoid being suspended. You can also set up an [auto recharge trigger](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135607-How-do-I-set-an-automatic-payment-recharge-trigger-) so that your account is automatically topped up when its balance gets low.

For errors, you can [set up webhook or email alerts for warnings or errors](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/troubleshooting/alert-triggers). Projects come with alerts for the 1st error, 10th error and 100th error every day and you can [add other alerts](https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/debugger/webhooks-triggers?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fdebugger%2Falert-triggers%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1) for all errors or any [error from the directory](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors).

Finally, if an account is suspended because it is suspected of fraudulent use, you will receive an email from the support team which will contain steps to recover the account.

Ultimately, I recommend that you always handle potential errors, account suspension is just one reason that your application may have to handle an error, so it is good to be prepared.